# Sabre Web Service GetReservationRQ Hotel Product Returning incorrect value for "isPast" element

Tags: soap, sabre

I am consuming the payloads from the GetReservationRQ API using Sabre Web Services. There is conflicting information in some segment data that is returned. Each hotel segment has two sub-elements - Hotel and Product. Why is there a difference in the "isPast" element in each of these responses? My truncated XML response is below. Can anyone at Sabre answer this?

```
<Segment sequence="1" id="223">
  <Hotel id="223" sequence="1" isPast="true">
    <Reservation DayOfWeekInd="2" NumberInParty="01" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/res/or/v1_14">
      <...>
      </...>
      <TimeSpanStart>2019-12-17T00:00:00</TimeSpanStart>
      <TimeSpanDuration>1</TimeSpanDuration>
      <TimeSpanEnd>2019-12-18T00:00:00</TimeSpanEnd>
      <...>
      </...>
    </Reservation>
    <AdditionalInformation xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/res/or/v1_14">
      <....>
      </....>
    </AdditionalInformation>    
  </Hotel>
  <Product sequence="1" id="223">
    <ProductBase xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/res/or/v1_14">
      <SegmentReference>223</SegmentReference>
    </ProductBase>
    <ProductDetails vendorCode="PH" statusCode="HK" previousStatusCode="SS" startDateTime="2019-12-17T00:00:00" endDateTime="2019-12-18T00:00:00" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/res/or/v1_14">
      <ProductName type="HHL" />
      <Hotel id="223" sequence="1" isPast="false">
        <Reservation DayOfWeekInd="2" NumberInParty="01">
          <...>
          </...>
      </Hotel>
    </ProductDetails>
  </Product>
</Segment>
```

Comment: I am speculating it is because you can have multiple "products" per Hotel in one PNR

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that. I'm confused as to how that would work as all of the "Product" elements I've seen in the payloads mirror the hotel data exactly (save for the past date thing). What other kinds of products can be present?